# BBC streaming video won't work on WP8.0 even though they use HTML5

Tags: video, flash-player, streaming

(This is UK-specific I think)

BBC.co.uk fairly recently started allowing users to watch streaming video within the browser even on mobile devices via HTML5, e.g. on my iPad I can watch live sport/music broadcasts directly in Chrome browser.

However on my 1020 using WP8.0, I get "your device isn't supported" whether I tell Internet Explorer to use mobile or desktop version. I'm unclear if the technology is actually lacking on WP8 (I think it has decent HTML5 support) or if BBC's website is simply blocking my device's browser user-agent string despite the device being capable.

Can anyone help me understand why it doesn't work (in as much technical detail as you like) and if there are any ways to make it work?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Although, when I go to bbc.co.uk on a PC, then in IE Developer Tools set browser profile to "Windows Phone" to trigger the mobile version of the website, videos stream just fine. Curious...

Comment: Have you tried using their [iPlayer app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=2c9d-47a0-a153-731b67b69b80)?

Comment: @RowlandShaw iPlayer only lets you see a very specific subset of programs previously broadcast... the WP version doesn't appear to even let you watch live broadcasts of normal channels.

Comment: It *might* be that they don't transcode with the relevant codec for all of their content, but that's speculation, and would really need input from someone at the BBC

Comment: From YouTube, my browser apparently supports H.264 within HTML5 which is presumably the same as iOS devices (they don't use WebM!)

Answer (score 1):

BBC is probably using HLS, a standard that requires an app by the provider.

The Swedish public TV, SVT, uses HLS as well. They have an app you can download that will enable HLS for svtplay.se.

Send an e-mail to BBC and ask them to do the same.